# Suppress very long webpack/Babel warning

Tags: webpack, babeljs, webpack-5

Running our script for `npm run start:webpack` on a project results in a pages-long bright yellow warning:

> <w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy/webpack.FileSystemInfo]
> Resolving '@babel/helper-compilation-targets/lib/filter-items' in
> node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread/node_modules/@babel/helper-compilation-targets/lib for build dependencies doesn't lead to expected result
> 'node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread/node_modules/@babel/helper-compilation-targets/lib/filter-items.js',
> but to
> 'node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread/node_modules/@babel/helper-compilation-targets/node_modules/@babel/helper-compilation-targets/lib/filter-items.js'
> instead. Resolving dependencies are ignored for this path. <w>  at
> unknown 4 @babel/helper-compilation-targets/lib/filter-items

(The stack trace goes on.)

This makes it hard to spot other warnings or errors.

I've tried upgrading @babel/core to 7.19 and updating its plugins, bisecting git commits to find where this started, searching the web—all without success.

How can I diagnose, fix, or suppress this warning?

Comment: Have been facing the same warning for a while but can't figure out how to diagnose it. Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: @Merott No; I still haven't fixed it. I have not had the opportunity to try your fix yet.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same warnings but with a slightly different path… Added line breaks and indentation for readability:

```
Resolving '@babel/helper-compilation-targets/lib/filter-items' 
  in <PROJECT_PATH>/node_modules/workbox-build/node_modules/@babel/helper-define-polyfill-provider/node_modules/@babel/helper-compilation-targets/lib
    for build dependencies doesn't lead to expected result 
      '<PROJECT_PATH>/node_modules/workbox-build/node_modules/@babel/helper-define-polyfill-provider/node_modules/@babel/helper-compilation-targets/lib/filter-items.js'
        but to 
      '<PROJECT_PATH>/node_modules/workbox-build/node_modules/@babel/helper-define-polyfill-provider/node_modules/@babel/helper-compilation-targets/node_modules/@babel/helper-compilation-targets/lib/filter-items.js' 
    instead. Resolving dependencies are ignored for this path.
```

The gist of it seems to be that Webpack is trying to resolve this:

```
@babel/helper-compilation-targets/lib/filter-items
```

And, it expects it to resolve to this:

```
<PROJECT_PATH>/node_modules/workbox-build/node_modules/@babel/helper-define-polyfill-provider/node_modules/@babel/helper-compilation-targets/lib/filter-items.js
```

But instead, it resolves to this:

```
<PROJECT_PATH>/node_modules/workbox-build/node_modules/@babel/helper-define-polyfill-provider/node_modules/@babel/helper-compilation-targets/node_modules/@babel/helper-compilation-targets/lib/filter-items.js
```

Strangely, it looks like `@babel/helper-compilation-targets` has itself inside of its own `node_modules` directory! ‍♂️

I managed to "fix" the issue by deleting that (extraneous?) package:

```
rm -rf <PROJECT_PATH>/node_modules/workbox-build/node_modules/@babel/helper-define-polyfill-provider/node_modules/@babel/helper-compilation-targets/node_modules/@babel/helper-compilation-targets/
```

You can also add a `postinstall` script to do it automatically after each install:

```json
scripts: {
  "postinstall": "rimraf node_modules/workbox-build/node_modules/@babel/helper-define-polyfill-provider/node_modules/@babel/helper-compilation-targets/node_modules/@babel/helper-compilation-targets"
}
```